# How to Query Cloud SQL from a Python Script in Compute Engine VM Instance

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform

On Google Cloud, I can connect my VM instance to the MySql client, but I can't do it from a Python script in the VM instance. Generally I can connect my VM instance to the MySQL client using:

`~$mysql --host=[CLOUD_SQL_PUBLIC_IP_ADDR] --user=root --password`

and then entering my password when prompted, allowing me to query Cloud SQL. However, I have a Python script saved in the Linux VM that can be run using the command: `~$python3 script.py`. I'm struggling to figure out how to connect to MySQL from that script, which should insert data into MySQL when executed. I've tried the following:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='xxxxxx', host='xx.xxx.x.xx',database='db_name')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
...
cursor.execute(sql)
cnx.commit
```

There's no error message, but when I query from outside the script I can see that nothing has been added to the database.

Comment: where are you checking for errors?

Comment: What is the sql query you are trying to execute?

Comment: We need more code. :) The code you have there seems fine so far, but we don't know what errors you're getting, and what the rest of the code looks like.